# How to get the date input from flatpickr?

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, flatpickr

I am changing my jquery ui datepicker to flatpickr. But i need to know how i can do this `$('#from2').datepicker('getDate')` for flatpickr. I cant find it online how to do it with flatpickr.

Thanks for your time.

***EDIT**

```
function getDays() {
    let start = $('#from1').datepicker('getDate'),
        end   = $('#to1').datepicker('getDate'),
        days  = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        if(days == 0 || days > 0) {
    $('#howManyNights').val(days);
  }
    return days;
}
```

*Doesnt work with flatpickr:

```
function getDays() {
    let start = $('#from1').val();
        end   = $('#to1').val();
        days  = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        console.log(days);
        if(days == 0 || days > 0) {
    $('#howManyNights').val(days);
    }
    return days;
}
```

days = Nan

Comment: should be able to get it just from the .val() of the input.

Comment: @ReverendPete Thanks for your answer. If i do that my calculation doesn't work anymore like it did with the previous datepicker *See Edit please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this, by making date objects out of the values of the flatpickr (working snippet that you can run)

```js
var from1 = flatpickr('#from1', {});
var to1 = flatpickr('#to1', {});

function getDays() {
    var start = new Date($('#from1').val());
    var end   = new Date($('#to1').val());
    days  = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    if(days == 0 || days > 0) {
      $('#howManyNights').val(days);
    }
    return days;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.3/flatpickr.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.3/flatpickr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

From:<input name="from1" id="from1" type="text">
To:<input name="to1" id="to1" type="text">
How Many:<input name="howManyNights" id="howManyNights" type="text">
<button onclick="getDays()">Get Days</button>
```

Comment: Man i was stressing out about this. But now thanks to you i have a complete working datepicker with disabled dates coming from the database. Thank you very much for you time and effort!

Comment: Hey! I have a little question, asking for tips. If i chose date 1/1/2020 until 1/5/2020. And those dates are disabled in the datepicker. How could it be possible for the user to change the date TO "1/1/2020 ----- 1/3/2020", i was thinking about that, don't know how i can make this nice for the user?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old topic but I think there is a better solution for this, at least with the current version (v4) of flatpickr.

A flatpickr instance has a selectedDates property which contains the array of selected dates (Date object) (see https://flatpickr.js.org/instance-methods-properties-elements/#properties).

Obviously, in case your picker does allow only one selection, the array will contains only one element.

And `_flatpickr` property will allow to retrieve the corresponding flatpickr instance if you didn't save it elsewhere (see https://flatpickr.js.org/instance-methods-properties-elements/#retrieving-the-flatpickr-instance)

If I take back your examples, this should work and I think this is much more reliable to than re-create the date from string:

```
function getDays() {
    let start = document.querySelector('#from1')._flatpickr.selectedDates[0];
        end   = document.querySelector('#to1')._flatpickr.selectedDates[0];
        days  = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        console.log(days);
        if(days == 0 || days > 0) {
    $('#howManyNights').val(days);
    }
    return days;
}
```